# Debian can't connect to internet using LAN

Tags: networking, debian, lan

I have a headless Raspberry Pi using Debian Wheezy.
I have a wifi dongle and if I connect my Raspberry using it, everything works fine: I can connect to the Internet, I can ping, I can update.

However, if I get down my wifi and set up the lan interface, I lost my internet connection.
I still can connect to it locally, using my laptop, but the connection doesn't exit (ie ping is not working).

Some useful info:

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.105
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.0.1
```

**ping www.google.com**

```
(nothing request timed out)
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a2:b5:20
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:97223 (94.9 KiB)  TX bytes:146140 (142.7 KiB)
```

**ping 192.168.0.1**

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 18007ms
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**netstat -r**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

well, I think that's all...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100% packet loss, when you ping your router, is a concern.  It indicates connectivity issues.  This can be caused by a bad cable (try a different one), MAC filtering being enabled in your router, a bad Ethernet port in either your Pi or your router, a bad iptables config, or a number of other issues.  Does anything else work using that router port and cable?

Comment: I checked EVERYTHING and finally I found the reason: my electrician created TWO separated LAN without telling me. I was plugging the cable in the wrong plug. Now I know how to workaround on it (and do a little talk with my electrician...)